# Configuring Intellij to behave as Eclipse

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

As i recently switched to Intellij from eclipse, i was looking for a way a way i can make Intellij shortcuts to behave same as Eclipse.

I found that there are individual shortcuts available to be edited, But that is too much time taking.

Any help on locating the easy way out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to *File -> Settings -> Keymap* you can choose **Eclipse** from the dropdown list.

[image]

More information regarding *keyboard shortcut configuration* you could find [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts.html).

Personally I would advise to learn the default shortcuts from Intellij IDEA.

Answer (score 0):

There is Eclipse predefined keymap in "Keymap" list at Settings | Keymap. 
Also check this article: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/eclipse.html